# Profiling single Web session

Tags: java, multithreading, profiling, performance-testing

While searching for a performance-problem in a Java-web-app, I would like to profile (via sampling) a single web session. The web-app is deployed on a Java EE Application-Server (either JBoss or WLS, so no OpenJDK-specific stuff possible)

Using a traditional sampler like JVisualVM or YourKit will only allow me to profile all running threads at once and thus will not reveal the CPU-Usage of said web-session separated from the base-load, which is already on the server. Part of the problem is, that there is (obviously) no technical connection between web-session and a single thread, i.e. every request might get a different thread out of the threadpool of the application-server.

My idea is to implement a sampler and register the thread associated with the observed web-session every time a new request is received from the server (deregistering the thread, as soon as the request is finished).

First question: Do you have to do this by hand or is there a tool already available to do it for you?

Second question (as I've found none and assume that this is a rather specific problem): What's the best approach?

Obviously one would try to minimize impact of the profiling to the application-performance. Also obviously, as I need to connect the (technical) thread info to application-specific data (websession-ID), this appears to be nothing, which can be done via JVMTI.

Leaves the option of coding a in-app-profiler, where a thread is doing the sampling via Thread.stackTrace or ThreadMXBean.getThreadInfo. Which is better? Is there another, better option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) can split the call tree for different URLs or query parameters.

[image]

If you can modify the URL or the query parameters for that purpose, then you will be able to separate the session from the background load. For example, you might add a query parameter `profile=true` that you only pass for requests that should be profiled.

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

http://messadmin.sourceforge.net/

This should help with what you want to profile.

Also, http://www.appdynamics.com/ and http://newrelic.com/ are very nice tools for profiling a web app.

Comment: While especially messadmin might be a tool, which could help me at another problem I'm facing, on first glance neither product features performance-profiling (in the sence of sampling) the application on a web-session-level. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have JProfiler, "*coding a in-app-profiler*" is certainly an option. Simply printing stack traces at specific intervals during a single method call already gives a nice snapshot view into what's going on.

Here's an example helper class that does that:

```
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

public class StackDumper extends Thread implements Closeable {
    static final String pid = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName().replaceFirst("@.*", "");
    final Thread t;
    final int step;

    public StackDumper(int timeStepMs) {
        setName("Profiler");
        this.t = Thread.currentThread();
        this.step = timeStepMs;
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(4096);
        for (int i = 0;; i += step) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(step);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }
            buf.setLength(0);
            for (StackTraceElement e : t.getStackTrace()) {
                buf.append("  ").append(e).append('\n');
            }
            System.out.print(pid + " @" + i + "ms: [" + t.getName() + "]:\n" + buf);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        interrupt();
    }

}
```

Use it as:

```
    try (StackDumper p = new StackDumper(100)) { // prints stack every 100 ms ...
        methodUnderTest();
    }
```

Comment: We have followed both paths, first trying to implement it "home brew style" and finally purchasing jprofiler. The difficulty is not so much getting the stack-trace information but doing so efficiently and finally to evalute the results (as in combining multiple similar stack-traces and so on.